# Transfering image/jpeg between two nodes of hazelcast

Tags: spring-boot, inputstream, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have two nodes in hazelcast, like client and server. Both applications are written on spring-boot. The idea that server goes to external api to get some image and it returns InputStream(after extracting `httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()` from `CloseableHttpResponse` object). Then client should get via Hazelcast (Callable object is responsible for this) this image and also will return to browser the byte[] in order browser will display the image.

This is a callable between two nodes:

```
public class ExecuteCallable implements Callable<IputStream>, Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5745765873707162281L;

private SomeObject someObject;

public ExecuteCallable(SomeObject someObject) {
    this.someObject= someObject;
}

public IputStream call() {
    try {
        
       DistributedExecutor distributedExecutor = (DistributedExecutor) ApplicationContextProvider
                .getApplicationContext().getBean(DISTRIBUTED_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME);

         return distributedExecutor.executeGetImage(someObject);
    } finally {
      //some tasks
    }
}
```

}

When server returns to client InputStream object, then i get this error:

```
Caused by: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: There is no suitable serializer for class org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream
```

I tried to return  ready byte[] object like `IOUtils.toByteArray(inputstream)`, but also got error.

The question is it possible at all to transfer some ipnutstream or its representation in bytes between two hazelcast nodes?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by converting the inputstream within try resources block and not returning the inputstream to external method.Otherwise the stream somehow is closed with exception:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify
```

So i just did this way:

```
    public byte[] doService(String url, SomeObject someObject )
        throws Exception {

    HttpUriRequest httpRequest = resolveRequest(url, HttpRequestType.GET, someObject);

    LOGGER.info("Generated following URL for request {}", httpRequest.getURI().getSchemeSpecificPart());
    try (CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpTransport
            .sendAndReceive(httpRequest)) {
        int httpStatus = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        LOGGER.info("responded with HTTP {}", httpStatus);

        if (httpStatus != 0 ) {
            byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent());
            return byteArray;
        } else {
           //some tasks
    }
}
```

And then i just return the byte[] object and my array is returned via hazelcast with callable(but defined for byte[]) to my spring-boot WEB Rest api and then it's returned to browser as image displayed.